# Position sticky + RTL + Box-shadow breaks on Edge

Tags: flexbox, microsoft-edge, right-to-left, sticky, box-shadow

The following code works well on Chrome, but on Edge the Sticky element is out of place

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.sticky {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 715px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(41,128,185,0.15);
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  height: 1600px;
  flex: 1 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
    <main class="main">
      <div class="content">Scrollable content here</div>
      <div class="sticky">Sticky content here</div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Result in Edge:[image]

I noticed that if I remove the box-shadow from the sticky component or the dir=rtl from the body. It all works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Edge, and after one resize the window in e.g. jsFiddle, it corrects itself.

What Edge also does, with `dir="trl"` set on the `body`, it render the scrollbar on the left side of the viewport, which e.g. neither Chrome nor Firefox does.

A workaround could be to instead of swap position with `dir=rtl` on the `body`, use Flexbox's own `order` property, and then set the `direction` on the inner elements to control the flow.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/exxos0v4/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /*width: 100%;                       default  /*
  /*flex-flow: row nowrap;             default  */
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.sticky {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 715px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(41,128,185,0.15);
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  height: 1600px;
  flex: 1 1;
  background: red;
  order: 1;                         /* added, move last  */
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main class="main">
      <div class="content">Scrollable content here</div>
      <div class="sticky">Sticky content here</div>
    </main>
</body>
```

---

Updated based on a comment.

After some more testing and research, trying to move the `box-shadow`, which obviously cause this issue, to an inner element such a pseudo, still offset the `.sticky` element.

So two simple solutions, so `dir="rtl"` can be kept on the `body`, is to either, using a pseudo, use an image to create the shadow, or, as in below sample, use the `filter` property.

Here I used a CSS trick to apply it only on Edge, but it can fully replace the `box-shadow`, and which way to go is more about how old browsers one need to support.

[Fiddle demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/exxos0v4/5/)

Stack snippet 2

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sticky {
  width: 300px;
  max-height: 715px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px 30px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 25px 0px rgba(41,128,185,0.15);
  background: yellow;
}

/*  CSS to target Edge only  */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  .sticky {
    box-shadow: none;
    filter: drop-shadow( -5px -5px 15px rgba(41,128,185,0.15) );
  }
}

.content {
  height: 1600px;
  flex: 1 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
    <main class="main">
      <div class="content">Scrollable content here</div>
      <div class="sticky">Sticky content here</div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thx for the elaborated answer. So you're saying that generally I might have problems with dir=rtl? I have a website that can be shown in both rtl languages and ltr languages, so the easiest way is to use the rtl and everything aligns itself. The alternative would me to add a rtl class and order everything manually?

Comment: @atlanteh Not generally, but on Edge `dir=rtl` obviously cause an issue when combined with `box-shadow`. I updated my answer with one more workaround, and hopefully that will suite you better.